# React toolbox's button not working

Tags: reactjs, react-toolbox

Here is the button,

[image]

and here is the button I clicked.

[image]

I can't say the button is not working, but compare to the example, it is so wire:

http://react-toolbox.com/#/components/button

The source code:

```
import {Button} from 'react-toolbox/lib/button';
```

...

```
<Button icon='add' label='Add this' flat primary />
```

The loader in webpack.config.js:

```
{
        test: /react-toolbox\/.*.css/,
        use: [
          "style-loader",
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
              modules: true,
              sourceMap: true,
              importLoaders: 1,
              localIdentName: "[name]--[local]--[hash:base64:8]"
            }
          },
          "postcss-loader" // has separate config, see postcss.config.js nearby
        ]
      },
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Include the material icons in `index.html`

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply install the following module.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-material-icons

Install

```
npm install react-google-material-icons
```

Use it

```
import MaterialIcon from 'react-google-material-icons'

<MaterialIcon icon="account_box" size={36}/>
```